# jQuery function needs clicking twice

Tags: jquery

if you visit one of our sites; http://skateboardingphoto.co.uk, you will see that there is a navigation bar at the top which can be hidden or expanded.

When being expanded (expanded by default, so have to minimise first), it needs to be clicked twice, but it would seem only the first time...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".open-close").click( function() {
        if (jQuery("#openClose").is(":hidden")) {
            jQuery("#navigation-wrap").removeClass("closed").addClass("open")
                    .animate({ 
                    marginLeft: "0px"
                }, 500 );
            jQuery.cookie('navbar', 'open', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
            jQuery("#openClose").show();
        } else {
            jQuery("#navigation-wrap").removeClass("open").addClass("closed")
                    .animate({ 
                    marginLeft: "-330px"
                }, 500 );
            jQuery.cookie('navbar', 'closed', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
            jQuery("#openClose").hide();
        }
    });  
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems to be working well for me, I only have to click once.

Comment: Im on a macbook and your page loads with the meny collapsed for me, and i only have to click once.

Comment: the problem is only when you collapse the toolbar and then reload the page: in that case a cookie is saved and it's the cookie that it's causing the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you save the state of the toolbar in a cookie and according to the cookie the user see the toolbar hidden or expanded. I think that the code that handles the cookie is this one (add the line i pointed out):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var navbarstatus = jQuery.cookie('navbar');
   if (navbarstatus == 'closed') {
     jQuery("#navigation-wrap").css("margin-left", "-185px");
     jQuery("#openClose").hide();//add this line

   } else {
   return false;
}
```

if you don't hide that div when you initialize the toolbar, the first time you click on it   `jQuery("#openClose").is(":hidden")` return false and executes the second part of the code (which hides `("#openClose")`) and so the second time you click everything is correct.

Comment: This problem - that the initial state is not being correctly set - is almost always the answer when something needs clicking twice the first time.

Comment: Fantastic - makes sense when you spell it out for me! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Is it browser specific? The most common reason for this is that the initial state is not correct - it works for me on FF.

Check that the is(:hidden) is being correctly picked up on the first time in the specific browser.